# URLs of created MediaWiki pages always include "index.php?title="

Tags: mediawiki

I am an absolute beginner at MediaWiki, and just installed an instance through my hosting provider. When I create a new page on the wiki, its URL is always prefaced by `index.php?title=`. I wonder if this is symptomatic of where I installed MediaWiki, or relevant to a preference I could modify in `local_settings`? I'd like pages to look like

```
http://wiki.stevenarntson.com/Group_1
```

rather than

```
http://wiki.stevenarntson.com/index.php?title=Group_1
```

Comment: I might expand this into a full answer later, but does https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL help?

Comment: This looks potentially very useful, and I see some other good advice about installation in there, too. I'm at the bottom of a big learning curve, and will set to it. Thank you for pointing me in this direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a full guide on how to do this in the [MediaWiki manual: **Short URL**](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL).

Essentially, you put your MediaWiki files in an unrelated directory (e.g. /w) then use the following to rewrite to the root:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

To tell MediaWiki you've done this, set the following in your LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgScriptPath = "/w";
$wgArticlePath = "/$1";
```

Comment: The MediaWiki manual page mentions a shortcut approach through the page `http://shorturls.redwerks.org/`. I went there, and followed the instructions, and it worked! Thank you.